# Regex to allow selection of from range not working

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I am using the following regex with a .net validator.

```
^100|150|200|250|300|350|400|450|500|550|600|650|700|750|800|850|900|950|1000$
```

The aim is to allow 1 of the values in the list.

However, whilst it works great with most, inputting '1000' produces an error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure your input is just `1000`? Any characters (even whitespace) after it will cause the regex to fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to limit the scope of your alternation:

```
^(100|150|200|250|300|350|400|450|500|550|600|650|700|750|800|850|900|950|1000)$
```

And of course you can optimize your regex:

```
^([1-9][05]0|1000)$
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. Now works - would never have come up with the optimisation in a million years.